# AttributeError: 'FiniteSet' object has no attribute 'difference'

Tags: python

After creating two sets with the "finiteSet" method, I get the "AttributeError" error when using the "difference" method.

While I can do "print (a-b)" with the sets I have created using "finiteSet", but I can't do with "print (a.difference (b))". Or when I create the sets directly, I can use the "difference" method.

I did not understand why. I'll be very happy if you can help.

```
from sympy import FiniteSet
from fractions import Fraction

k = {2,3,4,5}
m = {3,2,1,7,5}
print(k-m)
print(k.difference(m))

s = FiniteSet(1, 1.5, Fraction(1, 5), 1, 1.5, 7, 42)
t = FiniteSet(Fraction(1, 5), 1, 5, 1, 1, 91, 87)
print(s-t)
print(s.difference(t)) # I'm getting an error here.
```

Comment: Where is `FiniteSet` come from? Please specify import statement.

Comment: why cant you use s = set(1,1.5,....) ? try it if can

Comment: I think `sympy.FiniteSet` is not derived from builtin `set`. So there is no `FiniteSet.difference` method.

Comment: I think this may be the reason. I thought my fault was because due to my code writing.

Answer (score 2):

From document: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#set,

> The base class for any kind of set.
>
> This is not meant to be used directly as a container of items. **It does not behave like the builtin set**; see FiniteSet for that.

And `FiniteSet` is not descendant of built-in `set`.
So you cannot expect `FiniteSet.difference` method even `set` has `difference` method.
There is no `difference` method in the document.